# error when using OWA access to mail server exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010

Suddenly it will come out the below error when accessing the exchange 2010 mail server using OWA after clicking sign in button on initial page?

***The website cannot display the page 
 HTTP 500
   Most likely causes:
•The website is under maintenance.
•The website has a programming error.

What you can try: 
     Refresh the page.

```
 Go back to the previous page. 

 More information
```

This error (HTTP 500 Internal Server Error) means that the website you are visiting had a server problem which prevented the webpage from displaying.
For more information about HTTP errors, see Help.***

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On the exchange server, check the services list to check if all related services are running. If not, check the event log as to why they won't run.

Comment: You could also try the brilliant `Test-ServiceHealth` cmdlet.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same issue and the Microsoft Exchange Forms-Based Authentication Service failed to automatically start. As soon as I started up this service, OWA started working again.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you are running SBS Server. Go to Services and start Microsoft Exchange Forms-Based Authentication service.

Hope this helps, from some one who has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Exchange Forms-Based Authentication Service. Starting this service fixed the blank page issue and allowed clients to authenticate correctly.